# Mongodb Collection name

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've created a database in MongoDB using mongoose. Although everything works fine, but when I check mongodb the name of the collection has extra 's' in its name. The collection name created is employees. What could be wrong, or is it just the naming convention of mongoose?

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

let employeeSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  email: String,
  department: String,
  doj: Date,
  address: String
});

const Employee = mongoose.model("employee", employeeSchema);

module.exports = Employee;
```

Comment: Its mongoose's naming convention

Comment: You can control your collection name by providing 3 third parameter like this:
 mongoose.model("employee", employeeSchema, { collection: 'employee' } )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you have two options for controlling document names in mongoose.

If you just want to disable pluralization, you can  do it with `mongoose.pluralize(null)` as in Ankit's answer.

And if you want to change your collection name whatever you want, you can do:

```
mongoose.model("employee", employeeSchema, { collection: 'myEmployee' } )
```

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't just add an extra 's' but it makes the correct plural of the name.

**For Example :** Mouse will be converted to mice

You can disable it by:

```
mongoose.pluralize(null);
```

Reference Link: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/5947